# URL при работе на локальном сервере(Ajax, Spring)

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

Есть веб-приложение на Spring MVC, клиентская сторона посылает Ajax запросы на сервер.

*Есть класс, замапленный на:*

```
@RequestMapping("/cars")
```

*Маппинг метода, принимающего Ajax запрос:*

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

*Ajax запрос:*

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/cars',
            data: msg,
            success: function(receive) {
              alert(receive);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

*Имя варника:* shop

**Проблема:**

Когда стартую через IDEA **localhost:8080/cars** запрос обрабатывается, когда
через сервер **localhost:8080/shop/cars** - ошибка 404

**Вопрос:** По какому адресу Ajax отправляет запросы - дописывает к корневомн url строку из поля url в его описании?

Comment: Есть url начинается с `/` то это абсолютный url, он используется как есть, без дописывания чего-либо. Лучше настроить IDEA так, чтобы url'ы были такими же, какие будут на боевом сервере.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Вообще говоря, предполагается, что условный админ может залезть своими шаловливыми ручками в дескриптор развёртывания и переопределить contextPath приложения. Вследствие чего реальные url-ы будут отличаться и от предполагаемых боевых и от IDE разработчика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У браузера своё представление о том, какой адрес является базовым. Причём отличное от представления серверной стороны. В Вашем случае это будет localhost:8080 хоть в IDE, хоть в сервере.

В JSP вызов ajax можете написать так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cars',
    data: msg,
    success: function(receive) {
        alert(receive);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

`pageContext.request.contextPath` будет `пустой` в IDE и `/shop` на сервере.
`url` соответственно `/cars` или `/shop/cars` в зависимости от ситуации.
И таким нехитрым образом будет работать везде. Даже если переименуете своё приложение, то всё равно будет работать.

Можно попробовать установить базовый адрес с помощью элемента `<base>`.

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"/>
```

И использовать относительные ссылки (без `/` спереди).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'cars',
```

Точно не знаю, но скорей всего сработает.
`<base>` заставит браузер (и как следствие ajax?) пересмотреть свою позицию относительно того, какой адрес является базовым для относительных ссылок.
 Но и Вам придётся пересмотреть все ссылки на странице и привести их в согласие с `<base>`.

Можно создать глобальную переменную javascript в первых строках JSP

```
<script>
    CONTEXTPATH = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"
</script>
```

И использовать её в скриптах

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  CONTEXTPATH + '/cars',
```

Comment: Пока не понадобится вынести js-код во внешние файлы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Да. `В JSP` как бы намекает на область применимости. Но если вынести в js-код, то это наверняка будет функция, вызываемая из того же JSP. А в функцию можно передать параметр! Или установить глобальную переменную в js

Comment: @Sergey спасибо